# Mixed Schema CSV Import Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a folder of CSV files that I want to read into a dataframe.  The problem is that While all contain the set of columns I need, some of them also contain other columns.  So for every CSV in the folder I want to only read in the common set of columns that I need.

For example:

Sheet 1 contains the columns:

Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, X

Sheet 2 contains the columns:

Column 1, Column 2, Column 3

I only need Column 1, Column 2, and Column 3.  Is it possible to take care of that on read or do I need to read them in separately and then select the appropriate columns and append them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **`for loop over all files`** in the directory and get only the required columns read from the file.

**`Example:`**

```
#files path list
file_lst=['<path1>','<path2>']

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#define schema for the required columns
schema = StructType([StructField("column1",StringType(),True),StructField("column2",StringType(),True)])

#create an empty dataframe
df=spark.createDataFrame([],schema)

#loop through files with reading header from the file then select only req cols
#union all dataframes

for i in file_lst:
    tmp_df=spark.read.option("header","true").csv(i).select("column1","column2")
    df=df.unionAll(tmp_df)

#display results
df.show()
```

---

In case if your files in the directory have **`column1,column2,column3..etc(required columns)`** in **specific order** over all the files then you can try as below:

```
spark.read.option("header","true").csv("<directory>").select("column1","column2","column3").show()
```